# If statement != is not working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I require another evaluation on my code

```
if %programtorun% != "" (
    echo test
    pause
) else if %foundbootable% (
    set oserrorcode=1
) else (
   set computererrorcode=2
   goto error
)
if %programtorun% == init.lua (
   set foundbootable=true
)
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. If you need more details, please ask.

Comment: you should use `NEQ` instead of `!=` . Also when comparing strings quotes are also compared so there's a chance that you should use `"%programtorun%"`

Comment: You haven't indicated what the original content of `foundbootable` is.

Comment: @Magoo it is set to be false prior to the if statements. thank you.

Comment: `if false (` is invalid syntax. The required syntax is `if string1 op string2 ` where the operator may be one of `== equ neq lss gtr leq geq` and the strings need to be quoted if they contain spaces or other separators. If each string is *purely* numeric then the comparison will be made on the basis of magnitude. It's also possible to use `if defined varname ` which will be true if `varname` is an existing environment variable (one that has a value assigned to it)

Comment: @CoffeeGamer, did you even attempt to read the help file for the `IF` command?  There is not a single reference to use `!=` as a comparison operator.

Comment: run `if /?` and see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use `!=` in batch files.  Second thing to watch out for are spaces.

`!=` is rewritten as `IF NOT <first>==<second>`  (also `NEQ` could be used, that is a second option but `NOT` has been longer around and does not need anything extra to work).

I have taken the liberty to rewrite your code, now it should work for you:

```
if NOT "%programtorun%"=="" (
    echo test
    pause
) else if "%foundbootable%"=="false" (
   set "oserrorcode=1"
) else (
    set "computererrorcode=2"
    goto :error
)
if "%programtorun%"=="init.lua" (
   set "foundbootable=true"
)
```

Comment: `if "%foundbootable%"` is not valid syntax, it must read `if "%foundbootable%"=="false"`! Consider to use switch `/I` for case-insensitive comparison...

Comment: @aschipfl true, missed that.  Will fix it, thank you.  I don't know the value for that.  The OP would have to add that to the question.